# What's the original size of a drawing (frame) in comics page

Tags: comics

Let's say I have a comics book page, e.g. Tintin - my book edition is [A4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size#A_series) size. And most drawings (frames?) on a page are about 5cm x 5cm or something around it.

I expect that author did not torture himself and he was not drawing those frames so small but they were scaled down to fit A4 sheet after putting in grid.

So what is the original size of such comics drawings? I assume every author goes its own way but I'm asking about typical/average, e.g. is it like every frame is A4 or smaller or bigger.

Comment: Only anecdotical evidence (but surely every artist has his own method): back in school, I interviewed two cartoonists, and they were both partial to about A2. One of them even drew just a half page at that size.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the exact comic, but according to [this source](http://www.tintinologist.org/forums/index.php?action=vthread&forum=10&topic=3500), Hergé mostly drew his pages slightly larger than A3*. And that usually one page indeed was done on one sheet although that was not always the case, in some cases the originals were strips reorganized into albums.

[image]

**Image 1**: Drawing boards of Hergé, showing them in original size. [Image source](http://en.tintin.com/news/index/rub/0/id/4537/0/herge-artist), same page contains other pictures too.

This is fairly typical for the era. It is also common today to draw each page on a separate sheet and then shrink the artwork down for digitizing. Off course not all cases can be enumerated every artist has hes own pipeline.

* Since original publications were also slightly larger